# Slight deviation between datetime.datetime calculations in Python 2 and 3

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, python-datetime

While porting some code from Python 2 to Python 3, the tests highlighted a numerical regression when computing dates with `datetime.datetime` that I'm having a hard time to explain.

**How to reproduce**

```
date_max = datetime.datetime(2016, 9, 28, 4, 21, 5, 228000)
date_min = datetime.datetime(2016, 9, 28, 4, 21, 4, 460315)
date_futur = date_min + datetime.timedelta(seconds=((date_max - date_min).total_seconds() / 2))
```

**Outputs**

Output from `print date_futur` in Python 2.7.12:

```
2016-09-28 04:21:04.844158
```

Output from `print(date_futur)` in Python 3.5.2:

```
2016-09-28 04:21:04.844157
```

**Issue**

This is just one microsecond difference, but it bugs me because I cannot explain it, so I do not know if I can update my test results with the new Python 3 behavior or if something more complicated is at hand.

**Possible lead**

Maybe it is due to how Python 3 rounds 0.5 to the closest even number, and not up like Python 2 ?

---

**Update**

Result of `(date_max - date_min).total_seconds() / 2` in both cases is 0.8441575 seconds. However, once handed to `datetime.timedelta` constructor:

Python 2:

```
datetime.timedelta(0, 0, 383843)
```

Python 3:

```
datetime.timedelta(0, 0, 383842)
```

So something wonky is happening in the `timedelta` constructor !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From datetime official Python 3 documentation:

> If any argument is a float and there are fractional microseconds, the fractional microseconds left over from all arguments are combined and their sum is rounded to the nearest microsecond using round-half-to-even tiebreaker. If no argument is a float, the conversion and normalization processes are exact (no information is lost).

Replacing with numerical values, we are doing:

```
datetime.timedelta(seconds=0.3838425)
```

The float value 0.3838425 is then converted to microseconds, which yields 383842.5 microseconds. It is then rounded to 383843 in Python 2 (.5 always rounded up) and to 383842 in Python 3 (rounded to closest even number). What was misleading was the fact that this value is then added to another date with an odd number of microseconds (460315), flipping the parity of the final result !

Answer (score 2):

The cause for this difference is the different division behavior of Python 2 and 3. Python 2 uses integer division while Python 3 uses float division.

`3 / 2` outputs `1` in Python 2 and `1.5` in Python 3.

So the culprit is this part of your code:
 `(date_max - date_min).total_seconds() / 2`

Using `from __future__ import division` will cause Python 2 to use float division. Changing `2` to `2.0` will also make Python use float division.

Comment: I tried replacing it to `/ 2.0`, Python 2 did not change its behavior. Maybe if you pass a float to `timedelta` it applies the `round` function to it, which could explain the different behavior ?

Comment: I think this might be it actually, if you do the calculation "by hand", `(date_max - date_min).total_seconds() / 2` gives 844157 **.5** microseconds... That looks suspicious right ?

Comment: @ValentinB. It converts it to `int` by using float version of `mod`: if `isinstance(seconds, float):
            secondsfrac, seconds = _math.modf(seconds)
            assert seconds == int(seconds)
            seconds = int(seconds)
            secondsfrac += daysecondsfrac
            assert abs(secondsfrac) <= 2.0`

Comment: Something does not add up in my theory though: if it was a rounding up problem, Python 3 would round **up** to the even number 844158, not down to odd 844157... But changing that division to float division in Python 2 does not yield the same result as Python 3 because it already is float division (the numerator is in seconds, thus it is already decimal).

Comment: @ValentinB. The "issue" is definitely in the creation of the `timedelta` object. `(date_max - date_min).total_seconds() / 2` actually return `0.3838425` both in Python 2 and 3. `print(datetime.timedelta(seconds=seconds))` returns `0:00:00.383842` in Python 3 and `0:00:00.383843` in Python 2.

Comment: Yes I just did the same check :) I updated the question with this info...

Comment: Thank you, your feedback lead me to the solution, so if you change your answer I am willing to accept it !